# Swap array element in java in accending order

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to swap an array in ascending order but somewhere I'm going wrong. I'm taking input using

```
int n = Integer.parse.int(args[0]);
```

but it isn't working. Below is the full code.

```
package tech;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Techgig {
    public static int ta[]={1,12,5,111,200,1000,10,9,6,7,4};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        System.out.println("Amount Mark has:");
        int rs=50;//Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        //int a=0;
        System.out.println(rs);

        // for(int k=0;k<ta.length;k++)
        //System.out.print("\t"+ ta);
        int min,temp;
        for(int i=0;i<ta.length;i++)
        {
            min=i;
            // System.out.print("\t"+ ta[i]);
            for( int j=i+1;j<ta.length;j++)
            {
                if(ta[i]<ta[min])
                {
                    temp=ta[i];
                    ta[i]=ta[min];
                    ta[min]=temp;
                }
                // System.out.print("\t"+ ta[i]);
            }
        }

        for(int k=0;k<ta.length;k++)
        {
            System.out.print("\t"+ ta[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working? This is much too vague. Describe the problem precisely, including exact error messages or stack trace you get, or the desired behavior vs. the observed behavior.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is `Arrays.sort(ta);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace variable **i** with **j** here:

```
      if(ta[i]<ta[min])
      {
          temp=ta[i];
          ta[i]=ta[min];
          ta[min]=temp;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason is you are comparing 'i'th index with itself which you assigned to min variable and hence it will never go in your if condition to swap.

You could resolve this as below by using i and j as index and checking between the two:

```
for(int i=0;i<ta.length;i++)
{
  // System.out.print("\t"+ ta[i]);
    for( int j=i+1;j<ta.length;j++)
    {
      if(ta[j]<ta[i])
      {
          temp=ta[j];
          ta[j]=ta[i];
          ta[i]=temp;
      }
     // System.out.print("\t"+ ta[i]);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic of comparison is wrong.
Refer to the below code. Instead of applying so much logic. Why not just call upon sort method like below?

```
public static int ta[]={1,12,5,111,200,1000,10,9,6,7,4};

    // print all the elements available in array
    for (int number : ta) {
      System.out.println("Number = " + number);
    }
    // sorting array
    Arrays.sort(ta);
System.out.println("The sorted int array is:");
for (int number : ta) {
  System.out.println("Number = " + number);
}
```